# NSURLConnection crashes my app if I scroll the table to end too fast

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

Hey, I got a little problem with NSURLConnection, my customcell class has a function that will load it's image with URLConnection. I call that function when the cell is being drawn and the problem comes when I scroll too fast(It draws more cells) the URLConnection crashes the app.
Problem seems to come when too many URLConnections are active, I am thinking should I make queue or something..

Here is what I get:
http://pastebin.com/CxhUEQbu

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint is near the bottom `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'`, but also at the top; `unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x72cfaa0`. Find out which instance 0x72cfaa0 is (probably an Array), and you'll find your bug (you're sending a message to an instance that it doesn't know how to handle). I could tell you more, but finding the bug is half the fun really.

Comment: It seems that releasing the receivedData at didFinishLoading function causes this, but I don't get why it only does it when I scroll the table fast?